# How to get localhost using PHP 7.2 on Mojave?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, localhost, homebrew, macos-mojave

I'm trying to get PHP7.2 working on localhost, but phpinfo() keeps saying 7.1.19 is in place while ~php -v tells me PHP7.2.18 is in place.

I run `~php -v` it says:

> PHP 7.2.18 (cli) (built: May  2 2019 13:03:01) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.18, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

```
~echo $PATH
```

> /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/opt/X11/bin
>   I installed PHP7.2 via brew in

```
➜  php@7.2 pwd
```

> /usr/local/opt/php@7.2

I expect te get on localhost PHP 7.2.18 in place.

**UPDATE**

Followed these instructions from the link mentioned by @mikken ([How to use the php that brew installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523183/how-to-use-the-php-that-brew-installed))

Edited httpd.conf in folder /etc/apache2

```
#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

If I uncomment the first line and comment the second line, I can run phpinfo() from localhost, however it says it's PHP 7.1.19 and `php -v` says 7.2.18

In case I comment the first line and uncomment the second line, localhost won't start and `php -v` says 7.2.18

I also followed these steps, but no luck either.

```
$ brew update php // get the latest homebrew php packages
$ brew install php@7.2
$ brew link php@7.2 // create an alias to this keg-only version; see comments output during installation
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile // add the alias to your path; see comments output during installation
$ source ~/.bash_profile // reload .bash_profile to use the new settings immediately
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

Also tried brew `link php71 --force` but that didn't help either.

So it seems the webserver doesn't start when I switch lines httpd.conf

Any steps I can take the get 7.2.18 going?

Comment: What's the actual message if you try to force the php 7.2 library?

Comment: Can’t establish a connection. “Firefox is unable to connect to localhost”.

Comment: The error of Apache starting up.

Comment: Any suggestion on where to look for solving this error?

Comment: Yes, find that log and have a look why it's actually not working.